# Tween two properties at once in Three.js with TimelineMax

Tags: three.js, gsap

TweenMax doesn't allow you to tween 2 or more properties at once in Three.js on the same tween. For example you can't tween `rotation` and `position` at once. You can only tween the `rotation` in one tween or the `position` but not both.

I've managed to do it by pushing 2 tweens in an array and calling `tl.insertMultiple(array)`.

Unfortunately, for some unknown to me reason, **it only plays fine the first time**. After `restart()`, the tween/timeline is broken/stutters/skips.

*Notice when the color changes to red it's no longer smooth animation.*

### [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/rt1qfv8a/92/)

```
/* TWEENMAX ANIMATION STARTS HERE
 p = position
 r = rotation
 t = time
*/

var miroKeyframes = JSON.parse(`[
{"t":"0"},
{"p":{"x":"0.050","y":"0.220"},"r":{"x":"0.246","y":"-0.444","z":"0.014"},"t":"0.29"},
{"p":{"x":"0.010","y":"0.060"},"r":{"x":"0.109","y":"-0.150","z":"0.150"},"t":"1.01"},
{"p":{"x":"0.746","y":"0.738"},"r":{"x":"0.109","y":"-0.050","z":"0.013"},"t":"1.67"},
{"p":{"x":"-0.495","y":"0.804"},"r":{"x":"0.097","y":"-0.040","z":"0.105"},"t":"2.63"},
...
]`);

// Setup a timeline object. Restart on complete.
var tl = new TimelineMax({ onComplete:restart }),

tweens = [];


for (var i = 1; i < miroKeyframes.length ; i++) {

  var keyframe = miroKeyframes[i]; //current keyframe
  var dur = keyframe.t - miroKeyframes[i-1].t ; //auto-duration


  tweens.push( TweenMax.to( obj.rotation, dur, { x:keyframe.r.x, y:keyframe.r.y, z:keyframe.r.z, delay:keyframe.t, ease:Sine.easeIn} ));
  tweens.push( TweenMax.to( obj.position, dur, { x:keyframe.p.x*20, y:keyframe.p.y*20, delay:keyframe.t, ease:Sine.easeIn} ));

  //Works with either one of these but not both. It will execute each consequently. I need both at the same time.
  //tl.add( TweenMax.to( obj.position, dur, { x:keyframe.p.x, y:keyframe.p.y, ease:Sine.easeIn } ));
  //tl.add( TweenMax.to( obj.rotation, dur, { x:keyframe.p.x, y:keyframe.p.y, ease:Sine.easeIn } ));

}

tl.insertMultiple(tweens);
```

Please let me know how to fix this and what's going on. I don't want to use 2 objects - 1 for rotation and 1 for position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came from [the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/20237-tween-two-properties-at-once-in-threejs-with-timelinemax) by **PointC** and **Dipscom**. Special thanks!

The first and easier solution is to use labels or `position parameters`. [Check the video tutorial.](https://greensock.com/position-parameter)

```
 tl.to( obj.position, dur, { x:keyframe.p.x*10, y:keyframe.p.y*10, ease:Sine.easeIn }, "label" + i );
 tl.to( obj.rotation, dur, { x:keyframe.r.x, y:keyframe.r.y, ease:Sine.easeIn }, "label" + i );
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/mirohristov/pen/YMbvwg)

The second solution is to use 2 timelines - 1 main time line and 1 mini-timeline to add both properties at the same time:

```
  tl2.to( obj.rotation, dur, { x:keyframe.r.x, y:keyframe.r.y, z:keyframe.r.z, ease:Sine.easeIn}, 0 );
  tl2.to( obj.position, dur, { x:keyframe.p.x*20, y:keyframe.p.y*20,  ease:Sine.easeIn}, 0);

  tl.add(tl2);
```

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/mirohristov/pen/xeNzdy)

Hope this helps.